# on copy() error redirect page - PHP

Tags: php

The normal `copy("thisflie.php","here.php")or die("error message");`

Can I use `if(copy()) { redirect page}`

If there is an error in the `copy()` how can I redirect the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php), you can see `copy()` return `TRUE` or `FALSE` so you can simply do:

```
if(copy($source, $dest) === false){
   // error here
}
```

Honestly, first port of call should be the docs. And as a side note, `or die()` should never be "normal", you should handle your errors, not just kill the script mid-execution.

Answer (score 1):

just use this

```
if(copy() === false){
   // error here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php
Return Values

Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

So yes , u can !